# Custom ListView not able to remove item from list

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, listviewitem

I have two custom listView such as ListView A and ListView B. On ListView A contains the list of items when I click item in ListView A it will be highlighted(ie check and uncheck) on the specific item/data is populating into ListView B it is working fine. But when I uncheck item from ListView A and similar way trying to remove that item from ListView B it is not working.

While removing an item from **custom ListView with check box** not removing an item from ListView. but I am able to add that item but not able to remove.

onitemtap event of ListView control on the specific condition I am trying to Add or Remove the item from a list.

```
public class TestIds
 {
   ObservableCollection<ListViewModel> ListItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ListViewModel>()
     {
     };

  private void ListView_ItemTappedEventArgs(ItemTappedEventArgs itemTapped)
    {
       items = itemTapped.Item as ListViewModel;
       if (items.IsSelected)
          {
            items.IsSelected = false;
            BindRemoveItem(items.ID, items.IsSelected);
           }
           else
            {
             items.IsSelected = true;
             BindRemoveItem(items.ID, items.IsSelected);
             }
     }

    //this is my code for binding and removing data from listView

  private void BindRemoveItem(string id, bool isChecked)
    {
      IDManager.GetIDList(list =>
        {
         foreach (IDEntities item in list)
          {
           if (isChecked == true)
            {
             ListItems.Add(new ListViewModel { Text = item.IDDescription + " (" + item.IDCodes + ")", ID = item.IDCodeID });
             }
             else
             {
               ListItems.Remove(new ListViewModel { Text = item.IDDescription + " (" + item.IDCodes + ")", ID = item.IDCodeID };
              }
            }
        CustomControlClass.ListView.ItemsSource = ListItems;
        }, id);
     }                  
}
```

Here `ListItems.Remove` I am not able to item from listview.

Comment: any reply.... on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the issue, although I am not sure If I understood your question correctly.

You are trying to remove a new object here

```
ListItems.Remove(new ListViewModel { Text = item.IDDescription + " (" + item.IDCodes + ")", ID = item.IDCodeID };
```

The comparison is being done by reference, and nothing is being removed in the end.

Instead you shoud do

```
ListItems.Remove(ListItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == item.IDCodeID))
```

That is assuming IDCodeID is a unique identifier of your object, if not then you should probably consider some other way of getting the reference to the object that you want to remove